# <img src> tag not displaying images on Mac machines

Tags: vba, macos, email, outlook, html-email

```vb
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim fname As String

fname = "C:\Users\urdearboy\Desktop\(VBA)\Mail Send\QR_Code.jpg"
    
Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
With OutMail
    .SentOnBehalfOfName = "fakeemail@fake.com"
    .to = Target
    .Subject = "Email with QR Code Attachement"
    .Attachments.Add fname, 1, 0
    .HTMLBody = "<font size=3>" _
      & "Hello " & Application.WorksheetFunction.Proper(Split(Target.Offset(, 2), " ")(0)) & ", " _
      & "<br><br>" _
      & "<img src=""cid:QR_Code.jpg""height=100 width=100>" _
      & "<br><br>" _
      & "Thanks, <br>" _
      & "urdearboy"
    
    .Send
```

The image (with file path `fname`) loads on Windows Outlook desktop app, web Outlook across Mac & Windows, but the image does not load in Mac Outlook desktop app.

Is there a way to embed this image so it loads for both Mac and Windows users?

Note: This is not a 'download image' issue. The users who have Outlook set to download all images, and the ones that don't, end up with the same output once they download the image.

This is how the image renders on Mac Outlook desktop app.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` MAPI property (DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F"`) on the attachment to the value used in the `src` attribute. Windows version is more forgiving and also looks at the matching file name attachment when it does not find one with the right content id:

Replace the line

```
.Attachments.Add fname, 1, 0
```

with

```
dim attach As Object
...
set attach = .Attachments.Add(fname)
attach.PropertyAccessor.SetProperty("http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F", "QR_Code.jpg")
```

Comment: I will give this a try tomorrow and update (accept) accordingly! I'm on PTO so don't have work computer - just didn't want to leave ya hanging thinking someone took the answer and ran (*never close question*)